# What is the difference between the Selenium Maven artifacts selenium-api and selenium-support within the Maven Repository?

Tags: maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver, artifactory, maven-dependency

I am seeing the following dependencies under Maven repository

1. `selenium-java`
2. `selenium-api`
3. `selenium-support`
4. `selenium-server`
5. `selenium-Firefox-driver` and so on.

> Link : https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium

While I understand the others, I am not able to understand the difference between the two:

- selenium-api
- selenium-support

Whenn should we use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Maven, you will find all *Selenium Maven Artifacts* directly in the [Central Maven Repository](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/seleniumhq/selenium/)

In order to start using any of the implementations in your Maven project, you just need to add the required dependency within your `pom.xml` (current release being *`Selenium v3.141.59`*):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

The diagram below shows the dependencies between the different *Selenium Maven Artifacts* as well as the most important *classes*/*interfaces* in those artifacts:

[image: Selenium_Maven_Dependencies]

If you know that you will only use a certain *WebDriver* implementation, e.g. the *FirefoxDriver*, you don't need to depend on the `selenium-java` artifact (which has a lot of transitive dependencies). Instead you can just add the `firefox-driver` dependency on the artifact you need.

---

### selenium-api

[selenium-api](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-api) artifact contains the following:

- *Selenium*
- [WebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.html)

---

### selenium-support

[selenium-support](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-support) artifact contains the following:

- [EventFiringWebDriver](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/EventFiringWebDriver.html)
- [PageFactory](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/package-summary.html).

Comment: Upvote the answer if this/any answer was helpful to you for the benefit of the future readers.